# Filtering Core Data for UISearchBar with Swift

Tags: iphone, swift, core-data, uisearchbar, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a UISearchBar thats hooked up to a table view thats populated by Core Data. I've been having a lot of trouble getting filtering to work. Most tutorials on this are extremely old and haven't worked for me. I was thinking about converting the entity to an array and doing the filtering on the array but I've read that that's inefficient. I'm thinking I should use NSPredicate, but I honestly don't know what to do. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Please post relevant code including your NSFetchedResultsController and SearchBar classes

Answer (score 2):

I've actually been working on a demo of this and I have just put it up on GitHub. It can be found [here.](https://github.com/iMac239/CoreDataSearchBarDemo) As far as the implementation of it goes, you have to set up `UITableViewController`, `NSFetchedResultsController`, and `UISearchDisplayDelegate` for your class:

```
class ContactsViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsController, UISearchDisplayDelegate {
}
```

And with this there will be two table views:

Your tableView from the tableViewController (`self.tableView`)

Your tableView from searchDisplayController (`searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView`)

You also make class variables for `fetchedResultsController`, `searchResultsController`, `appDelegate`, and `managedObjectContext`:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate

var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? {
    get {
        if let delegate = appDelegate {
            return delegate.managedObjectContext
    }
    return nil
    }
}

var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController?
var searchResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController?
```

In the `viewDidLoad()` you must register your cell for your `searchResultsTableView` because it does not exist in interface:

```
searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CellID")
```

It is also here that you setup your fetchRequest:

```
fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: someFetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        fetchedResultsController?.delegate = self
        fetchedResultsController?.performFetch(nil)
```

You will need a function that returns which FRC you will need depending on the tableView. You make this function return a `NSFetchedResultsController` and you will use this in all of the table view functions where you pull data from the FRC such as `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` because it will get you the correct set of data

```
func fetchedResultsControllerForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> NSFetchedResultsController? {
    return tableView == searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView ? searchResultsController? : fetchedResultsController?
}
```

Finally, you need to implement `searchDisplayControllerWillUnloadSearchResults` and `searchDisplayControllerShouldReloadTableForSearchString`:

```
func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController, willUnloadSearchResultsTableView tableView: UITableView) {
        searchResultsController?.delegate = nil
        searchResultsController = nil
    }

func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool {

    let firstNamePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "nameFirst CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchString.lowercaseString)
    let lastNamePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "nameLast CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchString.lowercaseString)
    let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate.orPredicateWithSubpredicates([firstNamePredicate!, lastNamePredicate!])

    searchResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: someOtherFetchRequestWithPredicate(predicate), managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    searchResultsController?.performFetch(nil)

        return true
    }
```

If you have any trouble filling in the other stuff, such as the data model or the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods, check out the [demo](https://github.com/iMac239/CoreDataSearchBarDemo)!

Comment: Important: UISearchDisplayController is deprecated in iOS 8. (Note that UISearchDisplayDelegate is also deprecated.) To manage the presentation of a search bar and display search results in iOS 8 and later, instead use UISearchController.

Answer (score 2):

As of iOS 8, the searchDisplayController is deprecated.